# laravel - get all belonging of specific user (filter with related model)

Tags: php, laravel

can someone tell get how to get all the fixtures of competitions user joined.

fixtures belong to a competition

```
public function competition()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Competition::class);
    }
```

competition has many users

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);;
}
```

this is my code (which is returning all fixtures (even user is not joined to competitions)

```
$f = Fixture::where('status','NS')
 -> (['competition'=>function ($q)
            {
  $q->has('users', function($q) {
}])
 ->orderBy('fixtures.kickoff','asc')->get();
```

Comment: I am assuming that You need all fixtures where user joined (competition wise) right?

Comment: HINT: `Fixture::whereHas("competition",function ($query) use ($user){
  
$query->whereHas('user_id',$user->id);
})->get();`

Comment: thats correct.
this is the error the above code gives

`      $active=$this->guard()->user()->id;
        $a= Fixture::whereHas("competition",function ($query)
        use ($active)
        {
            $query->whereHas('user_id',$active);
        })->get();
        return $a;
`
TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::whereHas() must be an instance of Closure or null, integer given, called in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
 Fixture::where('status','NS')
 ->whereHas("competition.users")
 ->get();
```